# What is the best site or book for practicing shell scripting?

Tags: scripting

I have learnt shell scripting basics from internet, bash scripting guide and other resources. But now I want to practice shell scripting, where can I find good problems?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Practical tasks to learn shell scripting](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/490/12779) or [What are good online resources for learning shell scripting?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9270/12779)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/) is the best resource I've used, by far. Rather than just explaining syntax and available functionality, it explains many of the common [pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) and [issues](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) related to shell scripting. While it does focus on Bash there are lots of tips around portability (especially for POSIX shells).

Comment: Thanks Lobo. This wiki is looking good and in a quick review I found some common mistakes I have made in past.